# Cannot Get Border to Wrap Around Everything in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a White Border Around Everything present in the `<main>` tag, but I have not had any luck. It will only to around the `<nav>` section for some reason. Help?

```css
header{
    background-color: #030303;
    color:#ffffff;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 3em;
    background-image: url("assets/dndlogo.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

#dndlogo{
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
}

header h1{
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}

#schedulebox{
    float: left;
    height: 750px;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    background-color: aqua;
    text-align: center;
}

#homecontent{
    height: 750px;
    width: 84.3%;
    float: left;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border: red solid;
}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #030303;
    font-family: Arial;
    float: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li{
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    height: 15px;
}

nav li:hover{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: black;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

footer{
    background-color: #030303;
    float: bottom;
    color: white;

}

#schedulebox h1{
    border-bottom: solid;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    background-color: #030303;
}

a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    color: black;
}

main{
    border: white solid;
    order-radius: 10px;
}

#wrapper{
    background-color: #030303;
}

#schedulebox{
    border: red solid;
}

#dragonpic{
    width: 1600px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>D&D WCTC Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Dungeons and Dragons: WCTC</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
            <nav><ul><li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  <li><a>Page2</a></li>  <li><a>Page3</a></li></ul></nav>
            <div id="schedulebox">
                <h1>Schedule</h1>
                <p>We will usually have games twice every week. However, we will switch games every week so please look at the schedule for the one you wish to join.</p>
                <h2>Campaigns in Progress:</h2>
                <ul><li>Plague of The Gods</li><li>Inheritence of Felwinter</li></ul>
                <h2>Upcoming Campaigns</h2>
                <ul><li>Plague of The Gods</li><li>Inheritence of Felwinter</li></ul>
                <h3>We run games at 5pm CST to 8pm CST on Wednesdays and Fridays 5pm CST to 8pm CST</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="homecontent">
                <img src="assets/dragon.png" id="dragonpic">
                <h2>Who are we?</h2>
                <h3>We are a local Dungeons and Dragons club at Waukesha County Technical College. We host multiple games occuring at the same time with as many as 6 players at once. Each party's actions effect the in game universe that other parties will have to deal with. We are always welcoming new members and are also looking for people looking to become Dungeon Masters!</h3>
                <h2>Looking to Join?</h2>
                <h3>Head over to our join page to learn how to get started!</h3>
            </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div id="footercontent">
            <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2020 Company</i></small>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am just trying to get a white border around the main website content and not the `<nav>` or `<header>` section. I've tried having a separate division in the code for the content, but to no avail.

Comment: it's 2020, time to put the `floats` down. Check out `flexbox` and `grid`. https://www.samanthaming.com/flexbox30/ & https://cssgrid.io/ are great places to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have clearfix hack to clear floats. Refer to w3schools [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp) for more info.

```
<main class="clearfix">
```

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```css
header {
  background-color: #030303;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 3em;
  background-image: url("assets/dndlogo.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

#dndlogo {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Serif;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}

#schedulebox {
  float: left;
  height: 750px;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-align: center;
}

#homecontent {
  height: 750px;
  width: 84.3%;
  float: left;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border: red solid;
}

nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #030303;
  font-family: Arial;
  float: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  height: 15px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: black;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

footer {
  background-color: #030303;
  float: bottom;
  color: white;
}

#schedulebox h1 {
  border-bottom: solid;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: #030303;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
}

main {
  border: thick solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #030303;
}

#schedulebox {
  border: red solid;
}

#dragonpic {
  width: 1600px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>D&D WCTC Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Dungeons and Dragons: WCTC</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="clearfix">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a>Page2</a></li>
          <li><a>Page3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="schedulebox">
        <h1>Schedule</h1>
        <p>We will usually have games twice every week. However, we will switch games every week so please look at the schedule for the one you wish to join.</p>
        <h2>Campaigns in Progress:</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Plague of The Gods</li>
          <li>Inheritence of Felwinter</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Upcoming Campaigns</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>Plague of The Gods</li>
          <li>Inheritence of Felwinter</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>We run games at 5pm CST to 8pm CST on Wednesdays and Fridays 5pm CST to 8pm CST</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="homecontent">
        <img src="assets/dragon.png" id="dragonpic">
        <h2>Who are we?</h2>
        <h3>We are a local Dungeons and Dragons club at Waukesha County Technical College. We host multiple games occuring at the same time with as many as 6 players at once. Each party's actions effect the in game universe that other parties will have to
          deal with. We are always welcoming new members and are also looking for people looking to become Dungeon Masters!</h3>
        <h2>Looking to Join?</h2>
        <h3>Head over to our join page to learn how to get started!</h3>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div id="footercontent">
        <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2020 Company</i></small>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

make a div under `<div id="wrapper"></div>` then give padding around 20px to the wrapper div , and then give border value to the new div you will make under the div with id wrapper

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the float:left, it worked for me like this.

```
#schedulebox{

    height: 750px;
    width: 15%;
    background-color: aqua;
    text-align: center;
}

#homecontent{
    height: 750px;
    width: 84.3%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border: red solid;
}
```

Then I added border to wrapper

```
#wrapper{
  border:1vw solid white;
    background-color: #030303;
}
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Since there are floated elements in `main`, you need to add `overflow: auto;` to `main` to include all floated elements in it.

```css
header{
    background-color: #030303;
    color:#ffffff;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 3em;
    background-image: url("assets/dndlogo.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

#dndlogo{
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
}

header h1{
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}

#schedulebox{
    float: left;
    height: 750px;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    background-color: aqua;
    text-align: center;
}

#homecontent{
    height: 750px;
    width: 84.3%;
    float: left;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border: red solid;
}

nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #030303;
    font-family: Arial;
    float: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li{
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    height: 15px;
}

nav li:hover{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: black;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

footer{
    background-color: #030303;
    float: bottom;
    color: white;

}

#schedulebox h1{
    border-bottom: solid;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    background-color: #030303;
}

a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
    color: black;
}

main{
    border: white solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#wrapper{
    background-color: #030303;
}

#schedulebox{
    border: red solid;
}

#dragonpic{
    width: 1600px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>D&D WCTC Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Dungeons and Dragons: WCTC</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
            <nav><ul><li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  <li><a>Page2</a></li>  <li><a>Page3</a></li></ul></nav>
            <div id="schedulebox">
                <h1>Schedule</h1>
                <p>We will usually have games twice every week. However, we will switch games every week so please look at the schedule for the one you wish to join.</p>
                <h2>Campaigns in Progress:</h2>
                <ul><li>Plague of The Gods</li><li>Inheritence of Felwinter</li></ul>
                <h2>Upcoming Campaigns</h2>
                <ul><li>Plague of The Gods</li><li>Inheritence of Felwinter</li></ul>
                <h3>We run games at 5pm CST to 8pm CST on Wednesdays and Fridays 5pm CST to 8pm CST</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="homecontent">
                <img src="assets/dragon.png" id="dragonpic">
                <h2>Who are we?</h2>
                <h3>We are a local Dungeons and Dragons club at Waukesha County Technical College. We host multiple games occuring at the same time with as many as 6 players at once. Each party's actions effect the in game universe that other parties will have to deal with. We are always welcoming new members and are also looking for people looking to become Dungeon Masters!</h3>
                <h2>Looking to Join?</h2>
                <h3>Head over to our join page to learn how to get started!</h3>
            </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div id="footercontent">
            <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2020 Company</i></small>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```